# Eficiência da execução de queries PDO PHP

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, pdo

Existe alguma diferença de desempenho nos códigos abaixo?

```
$result = $pdo->query($sql);
foreach($result as $reg){ ... }
```

e...

```
foreach($pdo->query($sql) as $reg){ ... }
```

Fiz alguns testes, mas o comportamento das execuções não me parecem ter padrão, de forma que não consigo concluir se há diferença. Às vezes, parece que o código 1 é mais rápido e às vezes parece que não há diferença alguma.
Gostaria de saber como o interpretador PHP trabalha em ambos os casos, e se há de fato alguma diferença de desempenho.

Obrigado.

Comment: Não tem diferença, é a mesma, só mudou a sintaxe.

Comment: Absolutamente nenhuma, você teria diferença caso `$pdo->query($sql)` fosse um [generator](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.generators.overview.php), o que não é o caso.`Às vezes, parece que o código 1 é mais rápido e às vezes parece que não há diferença alguma.`: fazer benchmarks de códigos é algo razoávelmente complicado, você vai ver variações de desempenho num mesmo código dependendo até da posição dos planetas no sistema solar, então eu recomendo que você entenda o que rola por baixo dos panos antes de sair rodando e contando segundos de execução.

Comment: Sim, é verdade. Por isso perguntei como o interpretador PHP trabalha com ambos os códigos. Muito obrigado.

Comment: @BrenoMacena cuidado maior tem que ser com o for( ; ; ), while() etc pois se colocar algo dentro, é processado a toda iteração. Na dúvida, chamar a variável em vez do método evita ter que se preocupar com isso.

Comment: Sim. Eu suspeitei que no segundo código o foreach executasse a função query todas as vezes. Mas isso não faria sentido algum, pois a meu ver o programa não funcionaria corretamente, o que não é o caso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Da forma que você faz não há diferença alguma quanto a performance. Os resultados serão os mesmos.

A questão da atribuição ou não da variável para iterá-la com `foreach` fará diferença nos seguinte casos:

- Desejo de alterar o valor do array no `foreach`.
- Foreach com referência

Exemplo:

```
$range = range(1, 10);

foreach ($range as $key => $value)
{
      $range[$key] = $value * 2;
}
```

Ou ainda com referência:

```
foreach ($range as $key => &$value)
{
    $value = $value * 5;
}
```

Quando fazemos no segundo caso, o `$range` será alterado por conta da referência.

```
 print_r($range);
```

A saida será:

```
   [
     5,
     10,
     15,
     20,
     25,
     30,
     35,
     40,
     45,
     50,
   ]
```

## Cuidado com Referências em Foreach

Apenas para complementar, quando fores usar referência no `foreach`, tome bastante cuidado, pois por ser referência, a variável que referência os elementos do `array` sempre referenciará o último elemento do `array`. Ou seja:

```
foreach ($range as $key => &$value)
{
    $value = $value * 5;
}

$value = 'Oi, eu sou o Goku';
```

A saída será:

```
[
     5,
     10,
     15,
     20,
     25,
     30,
     35,
     40,
     45,
     "Oi, eu sou o Goku",
   ]
```

Para resolver isso, você deve usar o `unset` em `$value`, para anular a referência e tal não ocorra, pois talvez você acidentalmente possa criar uma variável justamente com esse nome.

Outro problema da referência com o `foreach` é a seguinte: O último elemento fica como o valor do penúltimo se você fazer outro `foreach` (se o segundo `foreach` for sem referência):

```
 $range = range(1, 5);
```

Isso gera:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Então, depois disso:

```
 foreach ($range as &$value) {}

 foreach($range as $value) {};

 print_r($range);
```

O `array $range` fica assim:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4]
```

Espero que tenha gostado das "dicas adicionais de referência".

Comment: Entendi. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Os dois foreach fazem a mesma coisa? Bacana essa segunda forma.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe olha a incrementação que fiz na resposta!

Comment: @DiegoFelipe leia "Cuidado nas referências" que eu acrescentei.

Comment: http://www.phpbench.com/

Comment: Por um minuto pensei que fosse o GuilhermeNascimento. Ele que sempre posta uns brench :D

Comment: Entendi, a referência fica até o fim do script.